# How to insert dbt test results into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, testing, jinja2, dbt

I would like to store all the dbt test results in a meta.test_result table.

I tried that:

```
{% test mandatory_field_check(model, column_name, severity = 'Error') %}

WITH column_check AS (

    SELECT
        a
        , b
        , c 
    FROM {{model}}
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ({{column_name}} IS NOT NULL OR {{column_name}} = '')


)

INSERT INTO meta.test_results (a,b,c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM column_check

{% endtest %}
```

The compiled code works, but running this test in dbt gives me an error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.)

Is there any best practice on how to save your test results to the db?

My desired result for a failed test would be one new line in the meta table and a failed test in dbt. A successful test should be succesful and not insert anything.

Comment: In the Exception/Error can you retrieve the sql string that is being executed that throws the error? That should make evident what the syntax error is.

Comment: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'. (156) (SQLMoreResults)")

I get that. If I convert the "Insert into" into a select it works fine

Comment: I asked for the *actual string that is sent to and executed by Sql Server*. You showed the template but did not include the end result of that template that throws the Exception. If you provide that it should be possible to find out why the syntax error is occurring.

Comment: The compiled script is

WITH column_check AS (

    SELECT
        a
        , b
        , c 
    FROM 'dbo'.'testTable'
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND test IS NOT NULL OR test = '')


)

INSERT INTO meta.test_results (a,b,c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM column_check


and it works when executing it in ssms

Comment: `'dbo'.'testTable'` <- that should not work in Sql Server, you cant change the name of an object into a string literal.

Comment: Just use Elementary Data (https://docs.elementary-data.com/introduction). Drop it in and you'll have a schema with all your test results and much more (I am not affiliated with Elementary but have used it with my clients).